# Adding user inputs from textfield into an array

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add users names that they have put in a textfield to a basic array. I don’t even know where to start!

The functionality basically is this:
User adds a name in text field 
Name is stored in an array so it can be referenced again somewhere else.

As you can tell I’m new to Xcode. I have been taking classes all of which have failed to explain this process. Any help is good Help ! Please :):)

// my view controller so far

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var name1: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var name2: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var name3: UITextField!

var namesArray : [String] = []



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    name1.delegate = self
    name2.delegate = self
    name3.delegate = self

    self.namesArray.append(self.name1.text!)
    self.namesArray.append(self.name2.text!)
    self.namesArray.append(self.name3.text!)



}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    if textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyType.done {
        self.namesArray.append(self.name1.text!)
        print(namesArray)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Can you show some of the code you've written in the view controller?

Comment: just added. is a mess..  I apologize in advance

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume you have all your logic mashed into one view controller since you are still learning and not worried about larger architecture decisions yet.

1. At the top of your class, you need an array variable:

   ```
   // Creates an array and initializes it to be empty.
   var userNames: [String] = []
   ```
2. I suspect you also have a button, so that when you press on the button, it grabs the text from the textfield and stores it in the array.  You need to set up an IBAction method for that button, and in that method...

   ```
   // Grab the text, save it in the array, and clear the text.
   self.userNames.append(self.myTextField.text)
   self.myTextField.text = ""
   ```
3. Later on, you can easily see the list of userNames by accessing self.userNames.  e.g.:

   ```
   let firstUser = self.userNames.first
   let lastUser = self.userNames.last
   let user47 = self.userNames[46] // assuming you have that many users
   ```

Comment: Fair assumptions. I only have a textfield and an add person button that allows for another textfield to appear. Should I implement a button to grab the text from the textfield. Or am I able to do it without one.. say once the go button is pressed on the keyboard that is given by the textfield it assigns it to the  object you displayed in step 2?? Thankyou for your help !!

Comment: You could do that via the keyboard, but that introduces other more advanced topics like delegates.  For simplicity I suggested a button, but by all means, feel free to look up the keyboard approach.  It's not that difficult, but I was going for a "new to swift/xcode" answer. :)

Comment: Seeing your code just now, my approach would be 1 text field, 1 button, and 1 table view. The user can enter the user name in the text field, and then click the button. When that happens, append the user name to your array and reload the table which uses that array as the data source.

Comment: This sounds like a good plan !  I will also read up further as I am interested on implementing the delegate method. I initially implemented a delegate but was unsure as to what protocol methods to use .. what would be your way of doing it? Just a summary of you’d like ?